# change network type to private from public

Tags: networking, windows-10, batch, lan

So i want to change the network type to private on all computer on the our firm network.

First idea was making a batch file, and run on every PC.
Is it the simplest way to do this ? And how can i change the type with batch ?
Is there a `netsh` command ?

Comment: Are all the machines on a domain?

Comment: @Narzard yes, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push out a policy in group policy or run this in powershell.

1. Run `Get-NetConnectionProfile`

This will return something like:

```
Name             : myCorporateNetworkName
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 6
InterfaceIndex   : 15
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : Internet
```

2. Run `Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "myCorporateNetworkName" -NetworkCategory Private`

Use the Name field in command 1 to enter into the name argument on command 2. Once you figure out the name on one computer, they should be the same on all the other machines. The script would just look like:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "myCorporateNetworkName" -NetworkCategory Private
```

Save this one liner as a `.ps1` file and you can run it on all machines.

Comment: GPO would be good, but I'm guessing that if they _had_ Active Directory, this wouldn't have been an issue in the first place, because the corp network would automatically get the "Domain" profile instead...

Comment: Right. Depending on number of hosts this might just be easier. This is definitely not the only way to do it. Be mindful that newly connected domain machines would also need to have this script run as well, as they would natively be using the defaults.